# Saving the objects detected in a dataframe: tensorflow object_detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I'm running the typical code found in the github repository tensorflow/object_deteciton:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection

Specifically the 'object_detection_tutorial.ipynb' file. The main loop is this section here:

```
with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    # Definite input and output Tensors for detection_graph
    image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
    # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
    detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
    # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
    # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
    detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
    detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
    num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
    for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
      image = Image.open(image_path)
      # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
      # result image with boxes and labels on it.
      image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
      # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
      image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
      # Actual detection.
      (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
          [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
      # Visualization of the results of a detection.
      vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          np.squeeze(boxes),
          np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
          np.squeeze(scores),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          line_thickness=8)
      plt.figure(figsize=IMAGE_SIZE)
      plt.imshow(image_np)
```

I'm just looking for some advise as to the best way to actually save what the image has identified int a dataframe that would ideally store the category of the object detected for each object detected in the image.

Any help would be appreciate (:

Comment: Can I just say, you have way too many comments there. Good comments are sparse, as good code is self documenting. Anytime you want to express *why* you chose a specific algorithm or technique that is not obvious, you should leave a comment discussing why the code is written this way. Anytime you have a piece of code which, despite well named identifiers, does not have a clearly expressed purpose you can leave a comment documenting what the code does. Don't leave comments that contain information that could have been learned by reading the code. Variable names, understandable operations, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're aware, but this code is taken from the tutorial on Github which is why it has comments in it I'd imagine....

Comment: Any feedback on this?

Comment: I guess the code has changed over time in the new TF version, but this piece as you show it is not in the file you described.

Comment: @user27074 so was the answer still helpful?

Comment: The syntax was helpful, but had to change the code a bit. See below @MikeWise

Answer (score 2):

Ok, rather late I guess, but I am working on this now. So I went through the same pain over a few days, and in the end got something to work. Just restricting myself to your code snippet, I added a few pieces and got this:

```
# Initialize hitlist
hitf = open("hitlist.csv",'w')
hitf.write('image,class,score,bb0,bb1,bb2,bb3\n')
hitlim = 0.5

with detection_graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
        # Definite input and output Tensors for detection_graph
        image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
        # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
        detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
        # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
        # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
        detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
        detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
        num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

        for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
          image = Image.open(image_path)
          # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
          # result image with boxes and labels on it.
          image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
          # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
          image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
          # Actual detection.
            (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
              [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
              feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})

          # Write the results to hitlist - one line per hit over the 0.5
            nprehit = scores.shape[1] # 2nd array dimension
            for j in range(nprehit):
                fname = "image"+str(i)
                classid = int(classes[i][j])
                classname = category_index[classid]["name"]
                score = scores[i][j]
                if (score>=hitlim):
                    sscore = str(score)
                    bbox = boxes[i][j]
                    b0 = str(bbox[0])
                    b1 = str(bbox[1])
                    b2 = str(bbox[2])
                    b3 = str(bbox[3])
                    line = ",".join([fname,classname,sscore,b0,b1,b2,b3])
                    hitf.write(line+"\n")

          # Visualization of the results of a detection.
          vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
              image_np,
              np.squeeze(boxes),
              np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
              np.squeeze(scores),
              category_index,
              use_normalized_coordinates=True,
              line_thickness=8)
          plt.figure(figsize=IMAGE_SIZE)
          plt.imshow(image_np)                      

# close hitlist
hitf.flush()
hitf.close()
```

Notes:

- There are three sections of added code, one initializes the `hitlist.csv`, one adds a line per "pre-hit" that is above the confidence limit of 0.5, one closes the file.
- It is intentionally not very "pythonic", it uses simple and obvious constructs to illustrate what is going on. Except the `",".join(...)`, which I like so much I could not resist.
- The number of pre-hits can be found by looking at the 2nd dimension of scores, or the classids.
- the classid that come back are `float`s even though you mostly need them as an integer. Conversion is easy.
- there may be some small copy and paste errors in here since I don't really have a MVE (Minimum Verifyable Example) for it.
- I am working with the `rfcn_resnet101_coco_2017_11_08` object detection model instead of the `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17` so my hitlist and scores are a bit different (worse actually).

Here is what a csv looks like:

```
image,class,score,bb0,bb1,bb2,bb3
image0,kite,0.997912,0.086756825,0.43700624,0.1691603,0.4966739
image0,person,0.9968072,0.7714941,0.15771112,0.945292,0.20014654
image0,person,0.9858992,0.67766637,0.08734644,0.8385928,0.12563995
image0,kite,0.9683157,0.26249793,0.20640253,0.31359094,0.2257214
image0,kite,0.8578382,0.3803091,0.42938906,0.40701985,0.4453904
image0,person,0.85244817,0.5692219,0.06266626,0.6282138,0.0788657
image0,kite,0.7622662,0.38192448,0.42580333,0.4104231,0.442965
image0,person,0.6722884,0.578461,0.022049228,0.6197509,0.036917627
image0,kite,0.6671517,0.43708095,0.80048573,0.47312954,0.8156846
image0,person,0.6577289,0.5996533,0.13272598,0.63358027,0.1430584
image0,kite,0.5893124,0.3790631,0.3451705,0.39845183,0.35965574
image0,person,0.51051,0.57377476,0.025907507,0.6221084,0.04294989
```

For this image (from the ipython notebook - but with a different object detection model).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think the syntax of the described object_detection.py file changed a bit. I adjusted the described answer a bit for the new syntax:

This is the position you should find in the code:

```
   # Actual detection.
      output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image_np, detection_graph)
```

And then this can be added:

```
  # store boxes in dataframe!
  cut_off_scores = len(list(filter(lambda x: x >= 0.1, output_dict['detection_scores'])))
  detect_scores = []
  detect_classes = []
  detect_ymin = []
  detect_xmin = []
  detect_ymax = []
  detect_xmax = []
  for j in range(cut_off_scores):
      detect_scores.append(output_dict['detection_scores'][j])
      detect_classes.append(output_dict['detection_classes'][j])
       # Assumption: ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax:
      boxes = output_dict['detection_boxes'][j]
      detect_ymin.append(boxes[0])
      detect_xmin.append(boxes[1])
      detect_ymax.append(boxes[2])
      detect_xmax.append(boxes[3])
      # Assumption: your files are named image1, image2, etc.
      Identifier = ("image" + str(n))
      Id_list = [Identifier] * cut_off_scores
      Detected_objects = pd.DataFrame(
        {'Image': Id_list,
         'Score': detect_scores,
         'Class': detect_classes,
         'Ymin':  detect_ymin,
         'Xmax': detect_xmax,
         'Ymax': detect_ymax,
         'Xmax':  detect_xmax
        })
```

Comment: I'll have a look at that when I get the chance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried both the above methods, but couldn't succeed. Mike Wise's code has a small error of missing the value of i. 
And User27074, there is a problem in appending the values of xmax, xmin, etc.

I tried a simple code, it works just the coordinates of the detected objects are saved in percentage and needs to be multiplied with the height and width of the image later.

```
detected_boxes = []
h = image_height = 500 #Change accordingly
w = image_width = 500 #change accordingly
#Columns' format 'ymin','xmin','ymax', 'xmax', 'class', 'Detection score'
for i, box in enumerate(np.squeeze(boxes)):
    if (np.squeeze(scores)[i] > 0.85):
        box[0] = int(box[0] * h)
        box[1] = int(box[1] * w)
        box[2] = int(box[2] * h)
        box[3] = int(box[3] * w)
        box = np.append(box, np.squeeze(classes)[i])
        box = np.append(box, np.squeeze(scores)[i]*100)
        detected_boxes.append(box)
np.savetxt('detection_coordinates.csv', detected_boxes, fmt='%i', delimiter=',')
```